# If the distance to previous terms in a bounded sequence is a large set, then is the set (of points of the sequence) itself dense?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Define the distance between a point $x$ and a finite set $X$ to be $ d(x,X) :=\ \displaystyle\min_{y\in X} \left\{\ d\left( x , y\right)\ \right\}.$

Let $\ (x_n)_n\subset [0,1]\ $ be a real sequence, and for all $\ n\geq 2,\ $ let $\ y_n:= d\left(\ x_n, \{x_k: 1\leq k\leq n-1\}\ \right).$

> *Proposition*: $\ \sum y_n\ $ diverges $\ \implies\ \{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\ $ is somewhere dense in $[0,1].$

And what about the converse of the proposition, that is:

> $\ \sum y_n\ $ converges $\ \implies\ \{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\ $ is nowhere dense in
> $[0,1]\ ?$

The idea of the first proposition is that, if $\ \sum y_n\ $ diverges, then $y_n$ is a "large set", and so $x_{n+1}$ is "far away" from members of $(x_k)_{k\leq n}$, slowly "filling up" an interval in $[0,1].$ So $(x_n)$ is dense.

Any ideas for how to prove or disprove these propositions, or ideas for constructing counter-examples?

Comment: What is your definition of “somewhere dense” for a sequence?

Comment: I meant the set. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: It seems that when editing the question, some part disappeared: we read "A sequence $(x_n)$ is said to be somewhere", but the end of the sentence is missing.

Comment: An interesting point is that density properties of $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ do not depend upon the order of $(x_n)$, while $\sum y_n$ depends upon it. So a follow-up question may be: given a sequence $(x_n)$, what subset of $\overline {\mathbb{R}}$ is made by $\sum y_n$, for all permutations of $(x_n)$? Are there only intervals? Open, closed? Etc.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni in response to your first comment, I have edited the question accordingly.